# Eclipse doesn't split string at line width when formatting

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, format, autoformatting

I'm currently working on an application in Eclipse where I'm running a really huge SQL statement that spans about 20 lines when splitting it in notepad to fit on the screen. Thus I want the string for the query also to be formatted somewhat more readable than a single line. All the time autoformatting normally worked when I used Eclipse but somehow now neither Ctrl + Alt + F nor rightclicking and selecting the "Format" option from the menu doesn't work to get a line break after a certain amount of characters.

I already checked the preferences where I already tried running my own profile with 120 and 100 characters line width but that didn't fix anything so far. I really don't know why Eclipse won't let me format this anymore. Normally Eclipse would be splitting the string into several lines in this case but I don't really know why this doesn't work anymore.

However other formatting is being fixed when executing autoformatting (e.g. `if(xyz){` still becomes `if (xyz) {`.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Formatting changes whitespace. It does not rewrite your code.

Comment: Yes, I've already read that in other articles but I could swear that Eclipse already split strings into multiple lines the same way like when you place your cursor in a string and press enter. However I now have a work around using the "Toggle Word Wrap" function in the menu or Alt + Shift + Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, autoformat as you described was never supported (at least as far back as 2008).  And I have been using Eclipse much longer than that

You can do one of several things.

- Simply insert the cursor in the string and hit a return.
- Toggle word wrap Alt-Shift-Y
- Try writing a regex to do what you want(not certain if this will work).